# I'm trying to make countinous adding in a calculator but I still wont get the sum I want, just the sum of the last 2 numbers

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

So, I started the tkinter tutorial from freecodecamp.org and I'm at the point of making a calculator. I'm following the tutorial to the letter while also experimenting a bit on my own. Here arose my problem, in the video the calculator outputs the sum of the 2 last numbers and that, if you press "number + number =" so no matter how many numbers do you press and the + after them, only the last two will be added. What I want to do is that whenever I press the + button, the sum is stored in the global variable but I'm having trouble doing that.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=3)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)


# button functions

def button_click(number):
    # e.delete(0, END)
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    temp = 0 + int(e.get())
    global v_keeper
    v_keeper = int(temp)
    e.delete(0,END)


def button_equal():
    temp = int(e.get())
    e.delete(0,END)
    e.insert(0,v_keeper + temp)


#button gui
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=button_equal)
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=79, pady=20, command=button_clear)

# put buttons on screen

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

# myButton = Button(root, text="Enter your name", command=myClick)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When `+` is pressed, you need to calculate the result if two numbers have been input and save the result for later operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* You should avoid global variables whenever possible. They tend to lead to unmaintainable, unstructured code.

Here is the solution path for your globals:

First: Define the global variable `v_keep` at the beginning of your script and initialize it to 0.

Second: In `button_add` you were assigning the wrong value to it. You want to store the current total sum there.

Third: You need to update `v_keeper` as well in `button_clear` and `button_equal`.

This is the part of your code I changed, in order to get the desired result:

```py
v_keeper = 0


# button functions

def button_click(number):
    # e.delete(0, END)
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))


def button_clear():
    global v_keeper
    v_keeper = 0
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    global v_keeper
    v_keeper = v_keeper + int(e.get())
    e.delete(0, END)
```

Updating `button_equal` is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver. On another note what weirds me out is the fact that v_keeper=0 is initialized in the beginning, I mean, doesn't the fact that the root.mainloop() in the end makes the entire code repeat also initialize v_keeper as 0 every loop or does that happen only at start?

Comment: Short answer: No. That is not what root.mainloop() does. In fact, `mainloop` is just a plain old python function that does not return until the tkinter GUI (in this case your calculator) is closed. It does *not* magically let your entire script start at the beginning again.